# Command-line interrupts in OS X vs Linux

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, terminal, process

Occasionally, when I'm developing on my Mac, I'll get a process that hangs. When that happens, I'll try the following:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the active terminal window
2. If nothing happens, I'll open a new terminal window and do `kill -SIGTERM {PID}`
3. If still nothing, close the terminal window.

I'm running into situations where after doing both 1 and 2, the PID is still listed in my list of processes. In other words, there doesn't seem to be a command-line option to kill the process - all I can do is kill terminal.

In Linux command-line environments, we obviously don't have option 3. So do command-line interrupts operate differently there? Is there another way to kill processes I'm overlooking? What is the 'last resort' option for killing a Linux process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same as in OS X: Send SIGKILL.

Comment: I don't know that I've ever upvoted such a short answer.

Comment: @killermist: Some things are hard to answer, and require a full essay in order to be complete. Some things are easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (control backslash), which sends the QUIT signal. This often works when SIGINT has been trapped.

Sometimes a process will ignore signals, because it is stopped.

You can use something like this, to kill a process gracefully if possible:

```
KILL() {
  kill -CONT "$@"
  kill -TERM "$@"
  kill -HUP "$@"
  sleep 1
  kill -KILL "$@"
}

KILL 12345
```

Even this might not always work. If there is some [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) error, such as a missing device, for example.